# Select entities assuming related entity does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My entity (Product) has a unidirectional many-many relation with another entity (Company) called **deletedByCompanies**.

I wish to select all Products that has not been deleted by a particular company. That is all products that are not connected through that many-many relation.

Tried:

```
$this->em->getRepository(Product::class)->createQueryBuilder('t')
->leftJoin('t.deletedByCompanies', 'deletedCompany')
->andWhere('deletedCompany.id not in (:companyId)')
->setParameter('companyId', [$companyId]);
```

But this simply does not return anything.
Schema is pretty straghtforward:

```
Product:
   id: int PK

Company:
   id: int PK

DeletedProducts
   product_id: int FK
   company_id: int FK
```

Entity definition in Product class:

```
/**
 * @var Company[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", indexBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="DeletedProducts")
 */
protected $deletedByCompanies;
```

Comment: *"I wish to select all Products that has not been deleted by a particular company."*. Do you mean only the **deleted** products that were not deleted by that company? Or all the products, including those not deleted at all?

Comment: Show the tables structure (the table names and the ID field names).

Comment: Only the NOT DELETED products by a Company.

Comment: Is `->from('Product', 't')` missing from the query? Also, what does it return if you remove the `where` condition?

Comment: No it's not that. I modified the query to be more specific.

Comment: You need another relation that shows product-company owning connection, to know which company has which products.

Comment: I'm not interested in that. My problem is specific and @Nils's answer partially solves it.

Comment: Hi @mike what you think about my solution?

Comment: hi @mike can ypu give me any feedback about my solutions? Do you have already implemented with the other answer? any feed is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with a `NOT EXISTS` clause on the deletedby table.

In the SQL dialect:

```
SELECT * FROM product p WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT * FROM DeletedProducts d WHERE p.id=d.product_id AND company_id = 2 );
```

In the Doctrine2 DQL, we haven't the entity `DeletedProducts` so we have to do a bit more stuff like:

```
$qb = $this->em->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle:Product")->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->Join('t.deletedByCompanies', 'deletedCompany')
    ->andWhere('deletedCompany.id  in (:companyId)')
    ->andWhere("p=t");

$mainQb = $this->em->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle:Product")->createQueryBuilder('p');
$mainQb->where($mainQb->expr()->not($mainQb->expr()->exists($qb->getDQL())));
$mainQb->setParameter('companyId', [$companyId]);

var_dump($mainQb->getQuery()->getSql());
$res =$mainQb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Let me know if I don't understand your problem.

Hope this help

Comment: If you want to reuse this code create a Custom Repository Class ... http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: Thank @GuilhermeViebig, of course! This method must reside in a Custom Repository Method! BTW is only an example for transform the query in a DNL style, so i don't cover this aspect, I hope Mike do a little refactoring and take care of your comments! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Doctrine, but I'm trying to help with some SQL knowledge. Following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.* FROM Product
LEFT JOIN DeletedProducts on product_id = product.id
WHERE product_id IS NULL OR product_id !=
    ALL( SELECT product_id FROM DeletedProducts WHERE company_id = 2 )
```

Some Explanation...

**DISTINCT:** Nessacary keyword to prevent redundancy. The same product can appear multiple times in the result of the *Left Join* if it is deleted by . *DISTINCT* eliminates those duplicates.

**WHERE product_id IS NULL:** The *Left Join* will also list the products which are not related to any company over the "DeletedProducts"-table. Since there is no relation the fields *product_id* and *company_id* are *NULL*.

**OR product_id != ALL( [...] ):** Now that we have got the products which aren't deleted by any company, we need additionally those which aren't deleted by a particular company. So we use an *OR* with a subquery which selects all deleted products of a certain company (e.g. company id = 2 as in the code example). Since we want to have the not-deleted products we have to use the "!="-Operator.

I hope this helps a little. Now it's up to you to "translate" the query for the usage within Doctrine.

Comment: Ok for now that must do. I did a low level query to get the record ID's I want to select. Then did pure Doctrine select based on simple 'ID in (...)' criteria. Thanks.